# Javascript looping on div changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I have something like this

```
if (document.getElementById('div_name') !== null) {
    if (check_page('/final.php')){
```

`check_page` is basicaly this `if

```
(window.location.hash.indexOf(str) != -1) {`
```

Then it runs some code I have, but only runs it once, how can I make it so it runs when there are changes inside `div_name`? Cause the page content changes but not url.

I need it to run non-stop, but I don't know how to do it.

Before I had it working but like this, but looks a bit rubbish and I wanted to do it so the code running would change according to the page I'm in, and then keep running:

```
$(document).ready(function loop() {
    var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * (4500-3500+1)+3500);
    console.log(rand);
    setTimeout(function() {
          press();
          loop();
    }, rand);
});
```

Comment: How do the changes inside `div_name` happen?

Comment: Do you know what changes the content in the div? Reason you can not have that trigger an event when it is done?

Comment: It's when a button is clicked, which is what the script does.
The code inside is like a bunch of If's that search for certains words that change. Like:
`if ($('#div_name("name")').length) {`
and it clicks on a button there, if there's another text it clicks another button. that is already done, i just dont know how to keep repeating that if's without a loop and calling the function inside the loop. I would prefer to run it again by detecting these changes.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is an event for the button.

```
$(document).on('click', '#yourButton', function(){
    /* Whatever your script does */
    if (document.getElementById('div_name') !== null) {
        if (check_page('/final.php')){/* ... */}
    }

});
```

If  you want to monitor #div_name itself, then you need to change it to a form element, like an `<input>` or `<textarea>`, then you can detect changes to it:

```
$(document).on('change', 'input#div_name', function(){
    /* Whatever your script does */
});
```